# Is the following local map unramified?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness, local-rings, ramification, regular-rings

Let $(R,m)$ and $(S,n)$ be two local rings, $R \subseteq S$, $R$ regular, $S$ a finitely generated and flat $R$-algebra, and $mS=n$.

In comments to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/390649/local-rings-r-subsetneq-s-with-r-regular-and-s-cohen-macaulay-non-regula/390651?noredirect=1#comment995737_390651) question it was claimed that in such situation necessarily $R \subseteq S$ is unramified;
however, I am not able to prove this. If I am not wrong (but I may be wrong), we need to show that $A/m \subseteq B/n$ is a (finite?) separable field extension.

> Could one please help or just refer to the relevant known results that help prove that $R \subseteq S$ is unramified?

Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4110414/flat-morphism-of-local-rings?noredirect=1#comment8498209_4110414) question, where the above question was discussed but not solved.

Thank you very much!

**Edit:**
Assume (in addition to the above conditions) that $A$ and $B$ are $k$-algebras, where $k$ is a perfect field.
Then:

**(a)** If $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, then $R/m \subseteq S/n$ is a field extension of finite degree (hence algebraic). Then the field extension is separable.

**(b)** If $S$ is an algebraic $R$-algebra, then $R/m \subseteq S/n$ is an algebraic field extension. Then again the field extension is separable.
(A special case when $S$ is algebraic over $R$ is when $S=R[w]$, where $w \in S$ is algebraic over $R$).

Also, I now see that there is no need to assume regularity of $R$.

Summarizing, we have:

Let $(R,m)$ and $(S,n)$ be two local rings which are $k$-algebras, $k$ is a perfect field, $R \subseteq S$, $S$ is an algebraic $R$-algebra (= every element of $S$ satisfies a polynomial over $R$), and $mS=n$. Then $R \subseteq S$ is unramified.

Please, am I missing something or am I right? Any comments are welcome.

Comment: This is not quite right; think about the case where $R$ and $S$ are fields.

Comment: Take an imperfect field $k$, $a \in k - k^p$. Then $k \to k(a^{1/p})$ satisfies all the assumptions in your question but is not separable.

Comment: Thank you very much, R. van Dobben de Bruyn and David Benjamin.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, please, if the fields $R$ and $S$ are perfect and $R \subseteq S$ is algebraic, then the extension is  separable (hence, since $0S=0$, the extension is unramified) or am I still missing something? Also, is the original claim (= first two lines in the question) true? It is assumed that $S$ is finitely generated as an $R$-algebra. (Is this enough or should $S$ be finitely generated as an $R$-module?).

Comment: I gave you a counterexample to the claim in the second paragraph. Note that the linked question was talking about characteristic $0$, where all field extensions are separable. If $R$ and $S$ are essentially of finite type over a perfect field, there is still a chance, but you did not put this assumption anywhere.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, thank you very much for your comment. Please, let me explain: I guess we are all talking about the following definition: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/024L which includes 3 conditions: Condition (1) is assumed to hold. Condition (2) says that the residue field extension is finite and separable. In the edit I have assumed that the base field is perfect, hence it remains to prove that the field extension is finite.

Comment: Condition (3) says that $S$ is the localization at a prime of a finitely generated $R$-algebra, and I had this condition in mind, but have not written it explicitly, so I apologize for not being clear. Summarizing, it remains to show that the residue field extension is finite dimensional. Now, if I am not wrong, finite dimensionality of that field extension will follow if we further assume that $S$ is finitely generated as an $R$-module.

Comment: Anyway, I like your last idea, that each of $R$ and $S$ is essentially of finite type over $k$ (our perfect base field) which means that each of $R$ and $S$ is a localization at a prime of an affine $k$-algebra. Now, assuming that $R$ and $S$ are essentially of finite type over $k$, please, could you prove that $R \subseteq S$ is unramified? This sounds a nice result (without assumung that $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module!).

Comment: With the help of the following resources, things are more clear for me now, so there is no need to further discuss my above question, unless you wish to add something, then you are welcome; thank you for your help! https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/024L   https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372926